# Reading from file returns null

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with this method. It's returning a null value, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I saw someone else explaining that the loop doesn't stop until null is reached and therefore returns null, but I don't understand how to get around this. Thanks in advance

```
public static int[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {

    Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(file);
    int a = 0;
    while(fileRead.hasNext()) {    
        a++;
        fileRead.nextLine();
    }
    String[]pieces = new String[a];
    while (fileRead.hasNext()) { // i think the error is happening right here
        String line = fileRead.nextLine();
    pieces = line.split(",");


    }
    fileRead.close();
    int[] piecesNum = new int [pieces.length];
    for (int b = 0; b < pieces.length; b++) {
        piecesNum[b] = Integer.parseInt(pieces[b]); // line 86

    }
    return piecesNum;
```

The error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Proj5.readFile(Proj5.java:86)
    at Proj5.main(Proj5.java:23)
```

Comment: `"// i think the error is happening right here"` -- no need to think about this, the exception message tells you **exactly** where the error occurs: `Proj5.java:86` or line 86 of your Proj5 class. Which line is this?

Comment: Only the first loop reads the file. The second loop reads nothing. Your `Scanner` has been exhausted.

Comment: You might get a `null` if you have two commas with nothing in between.  Also I think if you have a comma that starts a line, or ends a line.

Comment: The null pointer exception that you are thinking you will get at // i think the error is happening right here" is not possible since you need to have fileRead as null. And if that is null, you should have got FileNotFoundException much before this when you instantiated Scanner. You have not caught any exceptions in your code you shared. So it would have asserted at that point itself. Now this post is just to make you clear that why it cannot be at the point where you thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outcome of `pieces[b]` is `null` and that cannot be parsed to `Integer`.

Try one of the following:

1. Handle the exception

   ```
   try{
       piecesNum[b] = Integer.parseInt(pieces[b]);
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
2. Verify that content is not null and is a digit

   ```
   String piece = pieces[b];
   if(piece != null && piece.matches("\\d*")){
       piecesNum[b] = Integer.parseInt(piece);
   }
   ```